# Bash getting integer expression expected

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have following script to check disk usage

```
    #!/bin/bash

# set alert level 90% is default
ALERT=10

OIFS=$IFS
IFS=','

storage=$(df -H | grep -vE '^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }')



for output in $storage ;

do
  echo "---------------@@@@@@@@@ output started @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@-----------"
  echo $output
  echo "---------------@@@@@@@@@ output end @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@-----------"

  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  echo "---------------###### useo started ######-----------"
  echo $usep
  echo "---------------###### usep end ######-----------"

  if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then

    echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" 
  fi
done
```

But when i am running this code i am getting the integer expression expected error at if conditional statement, Here is the output of this script

```
  97% /dev/sda1
1% udev
0% none
2% none
---------------@@@@@@@@@ output end @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@-----------
---------------###### useo started ######-----------
97
1
0
2
---------------###### usep end ######-----------
./fordiskfor.sh: line 24: [: 97
1
0
2: integer expression expected
```

Comment: `$usep` contains no integer.

Comment: what should i do

Answer (score 2):

The problem is there:

```
if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then
  ...
fi
```

`$usep` contains multiple lines of digits. To cycle trough all of them use somthing like this instead of that part:

```
for $space in $usep;
do
  if [ $space -ge $ALERT ]; then
    echo "Running out of space..."
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The value stored in the variable `$storage` comprises of multiple lines. As a result, `$output` will also contain multiple lines, and so will `$usep`.

You can extract and compare all values stored in `$usep`, one by one, using another `for` loop as mentioned in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167915/48188) answer. Or you can use `while` statement as follows:

```
echo $storage | while read output
do      
    ...
    ...

    if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then    
    echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Is this anything other than a repost of the question?

Comment: I used `while`, whereas question contains `for` loop.

Comment: Well rather than reprinting the whole script, perhaps just the relevent line and an explanation of why yuo think that is a better approach...

Comment: I am very poor at explaining things. You could edit my answer if you wish to.

Comment: @jasonwryan - I've tried to make my answer acceptable to you. Hope this answer makes you happy.